# Ubuntu 20.04 no sound in headphones until microphone is chosen

Tags: sound, alsa, microphone, headphones

I have a Dell Vostro 14 5490. It came withUbuntu 18.04 preinstalled, and now I installed 20.04. It has sound from internal speakers, and microphone works correctly. But when I insert headphones, output device changes from

> Speakers - sof-hda-dsp

to

> Headphones - sof-hda-dsp

but there is no sound.

I have to go to sound settings, and select input device manually. And for some reason it lets me select from 3 devices:

> Digital Microphone - sof-hda-dsp

> Headphones Stereo Microphone - sof-hda-dsp

> Headset Mono Microphone - sof-hda-dsp

And for sound to appear in headphones, I have to select Mono Microphone.

Output of `cat /proc/asound/card0/codec* | grep Codec`:

```
Codec: Realtek ALC3204
Codec: Intel Kabylake HDMI
```

This situation is really annoying. Is there any way to force microphone change when headphones inserted, or for headphones to be independent from microphone? And why there are two microphones?